# Data.Dependent.Map examples

Tags: haskell, dictionary, existential-type

Are there any examples anywhere of how to use the [`DMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map/docs/Data-Dependent-Map.html) type? The package documentation is very learned, and I know it if for reference only, but it is singularly unhelpful for one getting started. Google reveals nothing that I can see.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that you think `DMap` will help you with?

Comment: I was thinking maybe it could be used to make a map where the values may have any different type depending on the type of key.

Comment: Well, there is one in the [README](https://github.com/mokus0/dependent-map)

Comment: `DMap` is used very heavily in `reflex`, so you can take a look at that package.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Updated README.md example](https://github.com/mokus0/dependent-map/pull/16) pull request. One need to implement `GEq` and `GCompare` instances for a GADT:

```
data Foo a where
  AnInt   :: Foo Int
  AString :: Foo String

deriveGEq      ''Foo
deriveGCompare ''Foo

dmap1 :: DMap Foo Identity
dmap1 = fromList [AnInt ==> 1, AString ==> "bar"]

main = do
  print $ dmap1 ! AnInt
  print $ dmap1 ! AString
```